# Problem running my first vue-charsjs with VUE on windows

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I need some help starting with vue-chart. I have studied the standard documentation and am still stuck.

1 - I created a default vue project with "vue create testgraph"
2 - I installed vue-chartjs and chart-js with "npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save"
3 - I replaced the App.vue file content with :

```
 <script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "GitHub Commits",
          backgroundColor: "#f87979",
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11],
        },
      ],
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

but I get the error "export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js'
Is there something I am missing when working with or installing chart.js? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi, Try removing the curly brackets from the import statement.

Comment: My thanks but i still get the same error "export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in 'chart.js' and a blank screen? do i need to add anything in main js? I currently reads :import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: Hi, downgrade your chart.js version to 2.9.4 `npm install chart.js@2.9.4`, because there are some compatibility issues between vue-chart.js and chart.js

Comment: Many thanks . i ran the command  npm install chart.js@2.9.4 and it confirmed that 2.9.4 installed and when i ran npm run serve it compiled with no issues but now the browser just shows a blank screen? i tried conf F5 but still blank. I just have a script in the App.vue as per example so do i need a template?

Comment: Yes, the template part is rendered on the screen.